# how to specify the extension target library with cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I have a Podfile like this:

```
target :'My App', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'AFNetworking'
  pod 'AFDropdownNotification'
end

target :'My App Extension', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

But after I run 'pod update', and then I run the extension target, it shows some error like this.

[image]